# Unable to update or install any package

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to update matplotlib but getting an error. **Error message :** EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment. environment location: C:\Users\DeepakKumar\Anaconda3 How to fix this issue?
Some Specs:

Anaconda3 2019.10

Python 3.7.4 64-bit

matplotlib 3.1.1

Comment: What command(s) did you execute?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, try to open your shell as an administrator and then run pip/conda install that will install it.

Also, I highly recommend using virtual environments to install libraries and avoid conflict in dependencies.

You can use virtualenv: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/
Or conda management environemnts.

Basically, you create a new environment:

`conda create -n my_env`

`conda activate my_env`

`conda install matplotlib`

This will avoid these kind of problems.
You can also read more about it here: [conda-envs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Search for Anaconda Prompt, Run the Prompt as Administrator (Right Click and select Run as Admin), then use `conda update <package>`, this shall solve your current issue, but this is just a workaround.

As Admin you should run `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`. This way your Anaconda should now update without admin related errors.

Comment: Deepak, Also use a virtual environment, @Victor Oliveira has summed it up pretty well.